# Making just the login https://, with ajax to avoid warning on redirect?

Tags: javascript, ssl, authentication

I'm thinking of enabling SSL just for my login.

In past, I recall that if you submit the login form to an HTTPS url and then redirect back to unsecured pages, a warning is displayed (transferring to non-secure page).

So if I was to handle the login with AJAX - using JS to post the form input to a https:// url, get response back and redirect with JS, that would avoid this warning correct?

Comment: Only using SSL for login defeats the purpose of using SSL. If you're not using SSL for the entire session, malicious parties can still sniff your users' cookies and gain access to their accounts. See Firesheep. Google "Firesheep" to see what I mean.

Comment: Right. However, I feel encrypting all logged-in pages would hamper performance since this site is already sluggish due to the fact is loads much data/imagery from an externally hosted FileMaker database.

Comment: If you use the proper technique to store cookies/sessions (i.e. in the database, encrypted cookies, key checking on the server), you should not have a problem with packet sniffing and can just use ssl on the login. This is how sites with lots of pages (i.e. Google) do it.

Comment: @Jordan, stealing a the password is much worse than stealing as session, so "defeat the purpose of SSL" is a bit exaggerated here.

Comment: If your login form itself is unencrypted, the transmission of passwords is still vulnerable (though slightly less than with no transcription at all). A man-in-the-middle attacker can inject javascript into your login page to steal the password.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't make an ajax request to an https ressource from an http ressource.
That would break the cross-domain policy

Comment: Cross-domain AJAX requests are not forbidden, just complicated and somewhat less well supported. See the documentation for [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).